# clusterSEs: bootstrapped SE on glm with interaction terms error

Tags: r, glm, statistics-bootstrap

I am running a logistic regression using `glm()` and want to calculate standard errors using `cluster.bs.glm()` from `clusterSEs`.

The first bit of code throws an error:

```
mod1 <- glm(lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + genstat + married +
            isced + factor(syear) + 
            I(factor(syear):married), 
            data = subw, 
            family=binomial(link='logit'))

library(clusterSEs)
head(subw)
se <- cluster.bs.glm(mod=mod1, dat=subw, cluster= ~pid ,  boot.reps = 10)

Error in cl(dat, mod, clust)[ind.variables, 2] : subscript out of bounds
```

When I remove the interaction term there is no problem:

```
mod1 <- glm(lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + genstat + married +
            isced + factor(syear), 
            data = subw, 
            family=binomial(link='logit'))


se <- cluster.bs.glm(mod=mod1, dat=subw, cluster= ~pid ,  boot.reps = 10)
```

Is there a programming reason, why this should not work? Since glm reports all coefficients of the interaction term, some are NA, I'd expect the code above to work nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to troubleshoot the example without a reproducible example. However, one potential solution would be to specify the interaction term outside the body of your model as Esarey does in his example on Github.

```
your_data <- your_data %>% mutate(your_interaction = var_1 * var_2)

mod1 <- glm(lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + genstat + married +
            isced + factor(syear) + your_interaction, 
            data = subw, 
            family=binomial(link='logit'))
```